# What's the meaning of bold part?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

[From this site](https://www.thedrum.com/news/2019/03/29/ms-appoints-odd-clothing-and-home-agency-restore-its-style-credentials)

> Together, ***we’ll be looking to build on early successes with our digital-first approach to campaigns including ‘Holly’s Must Haves’ and to better utilise data for ‘always on’ cross-channel campaigns.*** There’s lots to do and we’re all looking forward to working together to make M&S more relevant, more often, to more customers.

1) What does **build on early successes** mean in this sentence? In Cambridge:

> build on sth : ***to use a success or achievement as a base from which to achieve more success:***
>
> *We must build on our reputation to expand the business.*
>
> *A good relationship is built on trust.*

If ***early successes*** are used as a base from which to achieve more, what is being building ( on early successes)?

2) our digital first approach to ***campaigns including "Holly's Must Haves"*** 
Is it the **approach that includes "Holly's Must Haves" or campaigns**?

3) ***...and to better utilise data for 'always on' cross-channel campaigns.***  is **better** being used as a verb in this sentence? If so how to understand this verb+ verb combination? Does this sentence mean: ***We're looking to improve the data that always-on cross channels use?***

Comment: If you're playing with Legos, what does it mean to "build on" several you've laid down together?

Comment: Are you only asking about *build on*, as indicated in the title of the question? Because you've put a whole lot more in bold that just those two words, and you ask about "the bold part" in the body of your question.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I actually want to know the meaning of whole bold part. I edited my question.

Comment: I believe your assumptions about the first two points are correct. As for the third, *better* is being used as an adverb, modifying the verb *utilise*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, the Cambridge definition you have cited fits this usage perfectly. The idea is that the "early successes" of the digital-first approach will serve as a foundation for further success, as the approach is refined and extended. Beyond "further success," we can't really say what is being built; the metaphor involved here is rather weak.

2) The implication is that "Holly's Must Haves" is the name of one of several campaigns in which the digital-first approach has been used.

3) Here, "better" is an adverb modifying "utilise"; "to better utilise data" means "to use data more effectively" or "to use data more efficiently." Thus, it's not "we're looking to improve the data," but "we're looking to improve the way(s) we use the data."